# How to handle error with retrofit and coroutines suspend

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

i built my app with rxjava and needed to convert to coroutines for the background work i need help to see an actual example using retrofit 2.6.0 and coroutines and a proper error handling methods thanks in advance

i tried creating a generic error handler for retrofit and a wrapper for network resource states of Loading Authenticated Error

```
class AuthRepository @Inject constructor(val authApi: AuthApi) {

    suspend fun Loginauth(email:String,password:String)= liveData {
        emit(AuthResource.loading(null))
        try{
            val response=authApi.login(email,password)
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                emit(AuthResource.authenticated(response.body()))
            }
            emit(AuthResource.error(response.message(),null))
        }catch (e:Throwable){
            Log.d("any","error occured ${e.message}")
         emit(AuthResource.error(e.message!!,null))
        }catch (e:HttpException){
            Log.d("any","error http error${e.message}")
            emit(AuthResource.error(e.message!!,null))
        }


    }



}
```

My ViewModelClass

```
       screenState.value= AuthResource.loading(null)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val source=authRepository.Loginauth(email!!,password!!)
            screenState.addSource(source){
             AuthResource.authenticated(it)
                screenState.removeSource(source)
                if (it.status == AuthResource.AuthStatus.ERROR){
                    screenState.removeSource(source)
                    AuthResource.error(it.message!!,null)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make the API call on the `ViewModel` and use the repository just to hold the comand to do it

Comment: I think that wat am doing can you help with practical example pls